# css not working wordpress on godaddy server

Tags: css, wordpress, server

In my wordpress theme has css version-2.css file i change in that file and uploaded to server but its not showing any changes. so i deleted file version-2.css file from server still not showing any changes after 24 hours i reload my website now all css gone which in version-2.css. i clear all caches but still not showing any changes so what should do?
[enter link description here](http://clinic2.cruxbytes.com/doctors/?by_name=&geo_location=&geo_distance=50&directory_type=doctor&speciality%5B%5D=)

Answer (score 0):

You first have to make sure that your new file exists, put the URL of that file directly into your browser and check the content. It should be the exact content you are expecting (the updated version of the css). You can use **control+shift+r** to [reload and clean the cache of the browser](http://www.zeigen.com/shortcuts/2008/06/25/force-reload/).

If your file is still not on the last version, maybe there is some server-cache and for that you need to do the following:

Check on your functions.php where the CSS scripts are being enqueued (using the function wp_enqueue_script), the 4th parameter of that function represents the to the version of the file being loaded, if you change that value WordPress will stop caching that version of the file and you will be able to see your new version.

For example, if the CSS its enqueued like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'genericons', get_template_directory_uri() . 'version-2.css', array(), '3.2' );
```

You can update the 4th parameter of the function on that like like this

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'genericons', get_template_directory_uri() . 'version-2.css', array(), '3.3' );
```

Note: I only updated the 4th parameter from 3.2 to 3.3, that will be enough to tell WordPress to refresh the cache.

Comment: @rahulpatil you can use [this tool](https://www.diffchecker.com/diff) to compare this to versions of your same css file: [version 4.8.1](http://clinic2.cruxbytes.com/wp-content/themes/docdirect/css/version-2.css?ver=4.8.1) and [version 44545](http://clinic2.cruxbytes.com/wp-content/themes/docdirect/css/version-2.css?ver=44545)... they are different and the 4.8.1 seems to stop suddenly.

Comment: Not to me @rahulpatil, I even made a test change the CSS link tag during runtime using the google DevTools and your website started looking good, here is what I did: [http://recordit.co/qkBzbYML1X](http://recordit.co/qkBzbYML1X)